# Domain services

Tags: service, domainservices

We have started our projects with DDD design principles, I heard that any business logic needs two or more domain objects interaction should be written as domain services.

My question is:

1. Since my business logic includes saving of more than one domain or access many domain objects for validation purpose, can I pass repository inside the service method or can I access using DIContainer.
2. In case of operation A I will build `List<Specification>` (Specification classes which contain validation) and pass on to domain services from application layer. So my domain service validates and does business logic.
3. Can domain service use CRUD operation in itself.

I am really confused where to draw a line between application service and domain service.

Can I get any good samples which has application services, domain services, domain specifications with repositories involved.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here: http://gorodinski.com/blog/2012/04/14/services-in-domain-driven-design-ddd/

Actually these rules apply:
1) domain entities do the job
2) if in some function more entities are involved, changed - a domain service may be the solution
3) no, domain layer should not know anything about: transaction, saving, locking, etc. neither should load entities... if you need something like that use INeedSomeStuffFromRepo. Interface is defined in the domain layer, implementation is inside app. services. This way you could also doi locking, f.e. IExecuteThisFncToLockBeforeManipulatingWithAnObject
4) saving, transaction is in the app service side. i use persistence by reachability, so even if i have  an aggregate, entity with other entities related, it's enough to save the parent...

Answer (score 0):

Domain service actually is the Pure fabrication in GRASP. everything does not fit in an entity or a value object.